# How much curvature of the Earth can be seen at altitude?

Tags: earth-observation

Is there an equation that produces the amount of curvature of the Earth one should see at the altitude of `x` (whatever `x` may be)? I imagine it would be a complicated equation, and not as simple as people who believe the earth is flat say. (of course it isn't that simple, they always forget to include altitude)